# Problem with deposit public payable

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ide

with this code not possible deposit. I don't get any special error, only:
id:6449ed342beaee3b82363f7ecafd8fead18e6bcc3c3ace01db679a48210ea403resMessage:REVERT opcode executed

but from shasta account I can money missing.

```
function deposit() public payable {
        uint256 amount = 520000; //msg.value;
        address payable addr = msg.sender;
        addr.transfer(amount);
}
```

Comment: The function sends 520000 wei from the contract's balance to the sender. Does the contract have enough balance to cover that amount?

Comment: Hi, i have checked with 0 and yes is success but if use tron wallet from google extension has enought money, so how is that possible? I used directly from browser and I'm connected successfully to wallet.I used shasta node.

Comment: Tthis is my js script:
 let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(".......")
 //console.log(contract);
 //let currentValue = await contract.methods.getBadgeOwner('withdraw').call();
 let currentValue = await contract.deposit(0).send();
 console.log(currentValue);

Comment: A contract can only transfers from its own balance it cannot transfer from an external wallet.

Comment: thanks i got it. first i need to send tokens in my contract. then tunction from contract can send money to another wallet...